# Octave - System of differential equations with lsode

Tags: octave

here is my problem. I'm trying to solve a system of two differential equations thanks to the two functions below. The part of the code that give me some trouble is the variable "rho". "rho" is a function which values are given from a file and that I tried to put in the the variable rho.

```
function [xdot]=f2(x,t) 
# Parameters of the equations
t=[1:1:35926];
x = dlmread('data_txt.txt');
rho=x(:,4);
beta = 0.68*10^-2;    
g = 1.5;         
l = 1.6;         

# Definition of the system of 2 ODE's :

xdot(1) = ((rho-beta)/g)*x(1) + l*x(2); 
xdot(2) = (beta/g)*x(1)-l*x(2);    

endfunction
```

.

```
# Initial conditions for the two variables :
x0 = [0;1];

# Definition of the time-vector -> (initial time,temporal mesh,final time) :
t = linspace (1, 10, 10000);  

# Resolution with the lsode routine :
x = lsode ("f2", x0, t);

# Plot of the two curves :
plot (t,x);
```

When I run my code, I get the following error:

```
>> resolution_effective2

  error: f2: A(I) = X: X must have the same size as I
  error: called from
  f2 at line 34 column 9
  resolution_effective2 at line 8 column 3
  error: lsode: evaluation of user-supplied function failed
  error: called from
  resolution_effective2 at line 8 column 3
  error: lsode: inconsistent sizes for state and derivative vectors
  error: called from
  resolution_effective2 at line 8 column 3
```

I know that my error comes from a mismatch of size between some variable but I have been looking for the error for days now and I don't see. Could someone try to give and explain me an effective correction ?
Thank you

Comment: It's hard to help you since we can't reproduce the problem without your data file.

Comment: I cannot give my date file because it is from private sources. This is a classic data file from which I extract the 4th column which contains 35916 elements.

Comment: Please read [mcve]. You don’t need to post your data file, but you can generate some random data with similar properties so your problem can be reproduced. If you want help, you need to make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The error might come from your function `f2`. Its first argument `x` should have the same dimension as `x0` since `x0` is the initial condition of `x`.

In your case, whatever you intent to be the first argument of `f2` is ignored since in your function you do `x = dlmread('data_txt.txt');` this seems to be a mistake.

Then, `xdot(1) = ((rho-beta)/g)*x(1) + l*x(2);` will be a problem since `rho` is a vector.

You need to check the dimensions of `x` and `rho`.

Comment: I see what you mean but I don't think that it will change the problem.x = dlmread('data_txt.txt'); can be replaced by u=dlmread('data_txt.txt'); and I will get the same problem.

Comment: @S.Pri, what is the shape of `data_txt.txt`?

Comment: This is a classic data file from which I extract the 4th column which contains 35916 elements.

Comment: Ok, I agree with you and that's the actual problem. "rho" is a vector and I cannot change that because it is a variable defined thanks values coming from a data file. How can I change " rho" into a scalar to not have my problem ?

Comment: I don't understand your question, you say you cannot change `rho`, then you ask how to change it?

Comment: If I answered you question, please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: As you said "rho" is a vector because it is a variable defined thanks values coming from a data file.But now, if "rho" is a vector it implies that there is a mismatch of size as you already said too. In order to solve that problem, I imagine that it will be necessary to transform "rho" from a vector to a scalar' (but i don't know how) ? Is it possible or not ?

Comment: I don't know what you have in mind, but I guess `rho = 1` will transform `rho` into a scalar? But I think this should be another question (don't ask question in comments...).

Comment: No, this is not another question. Ok I see that you don't understand me so I'm going back to what you said. You said in your first answer that it will be a problem if "rho" is a vector and this is the problem that I already noticed. So I ask you how to solve that problem and one of my suggestion was to transform "rho" which is a function of time (of the values that I had in my data file) and a vector into a scalar (=a kind of "casting" like in programmation) but I don't know how to do so.

Comment: @S.Pri I cannot read your mind, so I can't decide what you want to do... sorry. I thought you wanted to know the source of the error message, and I found it. Good luck.

Comment: @S.Pri: If this doesn’t answer your question, then please update your question to make it clear what you are asking. The comments are meant for asking for clarification, not to clarify things. Comments can be deleted. We want the text of your question to be complete and self-contained, the goal of this site is to collect useful questions and answers.